# How do I use a Whitelist approach for some files with App Armor?

Tags: security, firewall, apparmor

I'm pretty new to using AppArmor and am unaware of all it's features. I was wondering if it is possible to apply Whitelisting behavior to some files with App Armor?

I think whitelisting and blacklisting is pretty well understood but, just so there are no misunderstanding, here is my definition:

Whitelist Approach to Access: tell App Armor that no Apps are to even be able to read certain files or write in them without being added to a white list (even if they don't have profiles).

Blacklist: as far as I can tell, this is what App Armor uses by default. If an newly installed application does not have an already existing App Profile, it will have access to everything that the user running it has access to (that is, until you make it's App armor profile and specifically interdict it).

That's ok for most applications, but I'd feel much better if for some important files, access is blocked to every app until I give the goahead.

Is there anyway of doing this? If so, can you please tell me how to do it?